# Wireless network stops working in XP until reconnect

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

I have rather strange issue with my wireless connection. Once in a while my computer just breaks all the internet connections and couldn't connect anywhere else. It does not however get disconnected from the network. Taking wireless connection down and then up again restores internet access but nothing else does. Other computer connected to the same wireless router works all the time.

So how can I diagnose what's happening and fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The computer isn't going into sleep/power saving mode and then not properly restoring the wireless card when it awakes is it? [I've seen this happen before](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/networking/?p=533).

Purposely put the computer into sleep/power saving mode to see if you can make it fail.

If that is the case, right click on the device in Control Panel -> System -> Hardware -> Advanced -> Device Manager -> Network Adapters -> *Your Network Card*

then choose the Power Management tab and try unticking the "Allow computer to turn off this device to save power" option

[image]

Comment: Properties page for wireless card does not seems to have this settings. Sleep mode is turned off and moreover it can loose all the connections when I'm actually working on it.

Comment: I should have followed your link :) Have turned power saving off, let's see if it will help.

Comment: Didn't help, I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you still ping your router when you're disconnected from the internet. Do start run cmd and type 
ping 
If you can try doing pathping www.google.com this should tell you where the break between you and the internet is.

Comment: No, it's unavailable. Another computer connected to the same router can ping it and can use internet through it at the same time as mine couldn't.

Comment: But connection icon shows that everything alright and I'm connected.

Comment: That's almost like an authentication failure. Does your ip address change?

Comment: No, my internal ip always the same. Public ip does change once in a while but it's no reason for only mine computer to lost all connections including the one to the router.

Comment: I was wondering if the computer was losing it's IP address when it loses it's connection to the router.  Are you using a mix of static and dynamic IP addresses? And if so is it possible that one of the dynamic ips is getting allocated to your static one?

Comment: I'm using DHCP on a router but it always assign the same ip to the same MAC. So ips is dynamic but on the other hand they always the same. I'll check what's happening with ips on both ends next time issue will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting wifi is, well, a b*^$h.

Start with your adapter and try to pinpoint if you're dealing with a hardware problem. Try connecting directly with a cable and keep an eye on it....if it stays connected you most likely have a bad wifi adapter/driver issue. Update the adapter's drivers, try again. Still a problem? Get your hands on another adapter...Still a problem? Try Winsockfix. Eek, so much more to check!  try these things and get back.

Comment: I'd rather move to Linux, it is easier :) All that is holding me now is broken support for stereo bluetooth headsets there. I hope they fix it soon :)