# Office Wireless internet disconnects too frequently

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

I am not a network expert (please pardon my bad explanation), but this problem has made me very upset.

In my office internet is shared among 15 users with the help of a wireless ADSL2 router. Actually this router is connected to another ADSL2 modem/router (the main one), We all work on laptops having wifi cards.
The problem is that the internet disconnects quite often. Although the router shows all the lights on and blinking but I think it is not able to supply or share the internet with all the users and hence disconnects.

One is able to surf when he switches off and then switches on his wireless a couple of times. All the nodes are being assigned IP addresses dynamically by the router.

Thanks

Comment: You should add more details if you want to get an useful answer: the model of your router, if some users linked through ethernet get disconnected too, if all the wifi users get disconnected at once or not, the electromagnic environment (microwave, power supply, nmr, ...), ...

Comment: The frequency of disconnection is much higher, all the users are not disconnected at once but some keep enjoying the internet while some are not. Nobody is connected via an ethernet. all of us share the connection with the help of an ADSL2 wireless router (beetel).

Comment: Have the same problem http://superuser.com/questions/28495/wireless-network-stops-working-in-xp-until-reconnect

Answer (score 2):

15 devices is quite a lot - is it a enterprise class wireless router or a commercial one?

It could be the router just can't keep up. On the other hand, if it is *every* device, this is almost impossibly to help without coming to your premises - I would say off the top of my head, check everything for interference, Microwaves, lights, or anything else that is wireless.

Edit based on more information.

On a few of the devices, can you try the following on any machine- (Assuming you know the IP of your router - lets say 10.0.0.1 for the first one, and 10.0.0.2 for the second in these examples

Open up three command prompts,

In the first type:

```
Ping 10.0.0.1 -t
```

In the second type:

```
Ping 10.0.0.2 -t
```

And in the third type:

```
Ping google.com -t
```

(Or your favourite ping-able site!)

Next time the internet goes out, look at all open windows and see where the break is, You should be able to say if it is the router you are all connected to, the router that acts as the modem or the ISP itself.

Comment: The router has been provided by the service provider and I am sharing it with other members with the help of another router which is a wireless one.
I have now edited my explanation again, please check it if I am able to explain myself better.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this on a stock commercial/household wirelesss router?

You may want to try an alternative firmware such as DD-WRT, Tomato, or Open WRT. I've heard that they are better at serving multiple users. Also, as Wil says you should check any other devices that may cause wireless issues. Maybe it would help to keep of log of when it disconnects and look for patterns.

Answer (score 1):

At home I have the same problem currently.
When I check the "radar", I find about 20-25 neighbouring APs. That makes for a lot of interference. Only in direct neighborhood of my own AP I receive decent speed and an interruption free connection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncheck the power management option for your Wireless card from device manager.

> Windows+R-->devmgmt.msc--->select wireless interface from Network
>   Adapters---->Properties
>   --->Power management---->

untick--> Allow computer to turn off this device.
For reference look at this image https://superuser.com/a/28533/935052
Untick the power management options.
Basically I had similar problem and by disabling power management option it went away. You may need to also check power management in BIOS also if it disables your wifi. If the problem persists still then get a USB wifi adapter and that should work usually ADSL routers broadcast on many channels and wireless devices built in on laptops have trouble getting connected to right channel. So an external USB wifi adapter becomes quite helpful in such situations.